# Parameter expansion with replacement, avoid additional variable

Tags: bash, parameter-expansion

I'm trying to join input `$*` which is one parameter consisting of all the parameters added together.

This works.

```sh
#!/bin/bash

foo() {
    params="${*}"
    echo "${params//[[:space:]]/-}"
}

foo 1 2 3 4
1-2-3-4
```

However, is it possible to skip the assignment of variable?

```sh
"${"${*}"//[[:space:]]/-}"
```

I'm getting `bad substitution` error.

I can also do

```sh
: "${*}"
echo "${_//[[:space:]]/-}"
```

But it feels hacky.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One option could be to set [bash](/questions/tagged/bash)'s internal field separator, `IFS`, to `-` locally and just `echo` `"$*"`:

```
foo() {
    local IFS=$'-'
    echo "$*"
}
```

Comment: And `join(){ IFS=$1;shift;printf %s\\n "$*";};join - 1 2 3 4` is generic and POSIX friendly.

Comment: @LéaGris Cool! Put that up and you'll have a vote.

Comment: @LéaGris You got it! :-)

Answer (score 1):

To answer your question, you can do global pattern substitutions on the positional parameters like this:

```
${*//pat/sub}
${@//pat/sub}
```

And also arrays like this:

```
${arr[*]//pat/sub}
${arr[@]//pat/sub}
```

This won’t join the parameters, but substitute inside them.

Setting IFS to dash adds a dash in between each parameter for `echo "$*"`, or `p=$*`, but won’t replace anything *inside* a parameter.

Eg:

```
$ set -- aa bb 'cc   cc'
$ IFS=-
$ echo "$*"
aa-bb-cc   cc
```

To remove all whitespace, including inside a parameter, you can combine them:

```
IFS=-
echo "${*//[[:space:]]/-}"
```

Or just assign to a name first, like you were doing:

```
no_spaces=$*
echo "${no_spaces//[[:space:]]/-}"
```